# Is there a lower bound on the number of facets of a full-dimensional convex polytope

Tags: polytopes

As the title say's: Imagine a full-dimensional convex polytope. Is there a lower bound (or even exact formula) for the minimum number of facets the polytope has?

Answer (score 3):

The lower bound is realized by a simplex, so the answer would be $n+1$ in dimension $n$.

You should be able to prove it by taking $n+1$ extreme points of the convex polytope.  That gives you a simplex.  Show that adding points to that, you are adding faces.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't it suffice to say that a full-dimensional polytope needs at least 2 extreme points which in turn means that we need to have at least n+1 irredundant inequalities (since each extreme point sets n inequalities to equalities). Each of these corresponds to one facet. Are there any arguments missing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow.  2 extreme points seems too few to me to fix anything -- in theory there is a continuum of inequalities that 2 extreme points satisfy.  But maybe I don't quite understand your argument.

Comment: Okay, once again :-)

We need at least two extreme points: If the polytope consisted of only one extreme point, it would have dimension 0 and thus wouldn't be full-dimensional. On the other hand, an extreme point is determined by setting a set of n irredundant inequalities to equality (face of dimension 0). So we need 2 different sets of inequalities while each set contains n elements. Thus, the minimum number of inequalities is n+1. Each of these inequalities determines in turn a facet when it is set to equality. That's my argument. Are there any mistakes?